# base64_encode an eval();

Tags: php, encoding, base64

Is threre a way to encode something like this :

```
eval("echo 'String';");
```

with **base64_encode**, and then to call **base64_decode** and get the result `String` without any **echo** or additional **eval** functions?

Comment: What is your initial input you want to encode?

Comment: You have to eval your code string at some point. You can encode the code string and eval it later after decoding, or eval it right away and use base64 on the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for `base64_decode` to *execute arbitrary code*? That doesn't work. It operates on *data*, not code, and so whatever you decode has to be a data string. Can't you just encode `'String'` directly? Otherwise, you'll have to run `eval` again to turn data into code: `eval(base64_decode($mysterydata));`.

Comment: thanks for the answer , now i know that this is impossible -_-

Answer (score 1):

eval('die(base64_decode("bla"))');

something like this?

if you want to obfuscate your code have a look at this site:
http://demo.dmwtechnologies.com/PHP/PhpObfuscator/index.php

Comment: thanks but i was searching for something which won't require additional eval(0 function.

Answer (score 1):

Not with `echo` in the `eval`, but how about this?:

```
echo base64_decode(base64_encode(eval("return 'String';")));
```

Comment: thanks but it won't help, because i have to encode a function